# Call function of class ONE from class TWO without extend?

Tags: php, class, reference

If i have two classes A, B and one does not extend another they are separate but both loaded into script can i still reference function in A from B?

```
class A {
    function one() {
        echo "Class A";
    }
}

class B {
    function two() {
        echo "Class B";
        A::one();
    }
}


$a new A; 
$b = new B;

$b->two();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access function in class A from non related class B using object of class A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101204/access-function-in-class-a-from-non-related-class-b-using-object-of-class-a)

Comment: You're not making the mistake of trying to use classes as way of setting up namespaces, are you? Because that's A Very Bad Idea.

Answer (score 2):

On the face of it, yes, you can do this. However, function `one()` in class `A` needs to be declared as `static` for your call notation to work. (This makes it a *class method*.)

The other alternative, suggested by the last lines in your code, is for the instance `$b` to call a function in instance `$a`. Such functions are called *instance methods* and are how you normally interact with an object. To access these methods, they must be declared as `public`. Methods declared as `private` can only be called by other methods inside that class.

There are several ways to call an instance method in your code. These are the obvious two you can pass in `$a` as a parameter to the function, or you can create an instance of class `A` inside your method.

What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can define it like this.

```
class A {
    public static function one() {
        echo "Class A";
    }
}

class B {
    function two() {
        echo "Class B";
        A::one();
    }
}


$a new A; 
$b = new B;

$b->two();
```

Comment: this works for me, but now this function had $this in it and because of static it does not work anymore, is there way to call variable inside same class without $this?

Comment: Actually its saying "Call to a member function one() on a non-object in"

Answer (score 0):

You can define one as static, but why would you do such a thing?

Comment: i need to put this in every file of 20 so i'd rather put just "$b->two();" than whole thing which is 5 lines long.