# Access function in class A from non related class B using object of class A

Tags: php, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call function of class ONE from class TWO without extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100757/call-function-of-class-one-from-class-two-without-extend)

why this does not work?

```
    class A {
        function one() {
            echo "Class A";
        }
    }

    class B {
        function two() {
            echo "Class B";
            $a->one();
        }
    }


    $a = new A; 
    $b = new B;

    $b->two();
```

Comment: The title should be: "Why should it work?" - Maybe error reporting helps, you should get a fatal error.

Comment: Look up [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0):

`$a` is not accessable in `Class B` in your example. Please read [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Try:

```
class A {
    public function one() {
        echo "Class A";
    }
}

class B {
    public function two() {
        echo "Class B";
        $a = new A;
        $a->one();
    }
}

$b = new B;
$b->two();
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because `$a` is not a global variable.
It should work if you declare `$a` as global in class B beforehand.

```
class B {
        function two() {
            global $a;
            echo "Class B";
            $a->one();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whilst this will technically work, it's a terrible thing to do. Better to pass `$a` to `B` as a dependency

Comment: I just answered the question. But you are right that something like this should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this is a variable scope problem. The scope of `B::two()` does not include the variable `$a` which has been declared in the global namespace.

The best thing to do is pass `$a` to `B` as a dependency. There would be several ways to do this...

For single use in `B::two()`

```
public function two(A $a)
{
    echo 'Class B';
    $a->one();
}
```

Then

```
$b->two($a);
```

---

As a property of `B`

```
class B
{
    private $a;

    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function two()
    {
        echo 'Class B';
        $this->a->one();
    }
}
```

then

```
$b = new B($a);
$b->two();
```