# Share same function call in two classes and avoid empty instantiation when not necessary

Tags: c++, inheritance

**My question**: Is it possible to share the **same call to function** between two inherited classes (say `Base` and `Derived`) and ---the key point--- **avoid an empty instantiation** in `Derived` when that function is strictly **specific** of `Base`, or and empty instantiation in `Base` when that function is strictly **specific** of `Derived`?

The reason to share the same call is that almost all code is common, just some peculiarities need to be resolved separately. For example:

```
class Base
{
    virtual BaseSpecific();    // Useful in Base
    virtual DerivedSpecific(); // Useless in Base
};

class Derived : Base
{
    BaseSpecific() override;    // Useless in Derived
    DerivedSpecific() override; // Useful in Derived
};

// f() is so similar between Base and Derived that is shared common in Base
Base::f()
{
    ...
    BaseSpecific();
    DerivedSpecific();
    ...
}

Derived::BaseSpecific() {}   // empty implementation in Derived, avoidable?
Base::BaseSpecific() { ... } // define the specific behavior in Base, OK

// or

Derived::DerivedSpecific() { ... } // define the specific behavior in Derived, OK
Base::DerivedSpecific() {}         // empty implementation in Base, avoidable?
```

Does C++ provide a solution to this? Is it inevitable?

Thank you in advance.

PD: This is similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100757/call-function-of-class-one-from-class-two-without-extend) but different in implementation.

Comment: Why would Base want to call a function that is DerivedSpecific?

Comment: Because code is 90% identical between Base and Derived, and for the remaining 10%, it is done specifically. Is an improvement possible?

Comment: It's hard to provide any advice without a real example. Certainly you can avoid `Derived::BaseSpecific() {}` by just **not** overriding the BaseSpecific function in Derived.

Comment: You can avoid an empty base implementation with `DerivedSpecific() = 0;` in the base class. For `BaseSpecific()`, if no `Derived` has a different implementation, just don't make the function virtual and don't override it - it will inherit. If only some `Derived` have a different implementation from `Base`, then only override for the `Derived` that do. Also, the link appears to be a completely different question about PHP?

Comment: Why not merge the two functions into a single `virtual void ClassSpecific()`? The base class defines it to do the base-specific thing, and the derived class defines it to do the derived-specific thing. The `f` function just calls `ClassSpecific()` and the appropriate thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

`final` keyword forbids overriding of the function. So `BaseSpecific` is suitable for the usage. If we don't want `DerivedSpecific` to be implemented in `Base` we should declare it as `pure abstract virtual function`.

```
class Base
{
    virtual void BaseSpecific() final;    // Useful in Base
    virtual void DerivedSpecific() = 0;   // Not possible to implement here with this declaration
};

class Derived : Base
{
    // void BaseSpecific() override; // Error, not possible to override
    void DerivedSpecific() override; // It is possible to override
};
```

But if you say so

> Because code is 90% identical between Base and Derived, and for the
>   remaining 10%, it is done specifically. Is an improvement possible?

A suitable solution could be implementing [template method pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method).

Possible implementation with the help of example from the link could be :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
    public:

    void templateMethod()
    {
        stepOne();
        stepTwo();
        stepThree();
    }

    protected:

    void stepOne() // And i dont want it to be overriden
    {              // so it is not virtual
        std::cout << "%45 of the code done." << std::endl;

    } 
    virtual void stepTwo() = 0;
    void stepThree() // Again i dont want it to be overridden
    {                // so it is not virtual
        std::cout << "Remaining %45 of the work done." << std::endl;
    }
}; 

class Derived : public Base
{
    protected:
    void stepTwo() override final // I want it to be final
    {
        std::cout << "%10 of the work done." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto obj = std::make_unique<Derived>();

    obj->templateMethod();
}
```

Output :

> %45 of the code done.
>   %10 of the work done.
>   Remaining %45 of the work done.

[run online](https://onlinegdb.com/S1J7M4MNI)

It is also possible to perform conditional actions with the pattern by changing declaration of the method.

For example :

```
bool stepTwo(); // Declaration
...
...
if ( stepTwo() ) // If second step succeeded
    stepThree(); // Perform step three
```

Comment: As far as I know, stepTwo() will have to be implemented as well in Base, because pure virtual functions must be overridden in all classes that inherit them in the first place. Derived may or not override it, but Base must, which is what I would like to avoid. I would like to "jump" directly to Derived without implementing it in "Base'.

Comment: @Victor You are free to change it from `pure virtual function` to `virtual function` according to your needs. I just demonstrated a possible implementation.